# How to access class probabilities in keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am training a model for which  I need to report class probabilities instead of a single classification. I have three classes and each training instance has either of the three classes assigned to it.

I am trying to use Keras to create an MLP. But I can't figure how to extract the final class probabilities for each class. I am using this as my base example: http://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the **predict** method of your trained model

> predict
>
> predict(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
>
> Generates output  predictions for the input samples, processing the samples in a batched
>   way.
>
> Arguments
>
> x: the input data, as a Numpy array (or list of Numpy arrays if the
>   model has multiple outputs). batch_size: integer. verbose: verbosity
>   mode, 0 or 1.
>
> Returns a Numpy array of predictions.

```
model.predict(input_to_your_network)
```

Answer (score 13):

In order to perform multi-class classification (nb_classes > 1) you have to prepare your model in a specific manner.

1. Make sure your labels are well-designed for multi-class classification. Have a look at the  [numpy_utils](https://keras.io/utils/np_utils/)
2. You have to use the categorical_crossentropy as objective function for multi-class classification (see [Keras objectives](https://keras.io/objectives/))
3. Your last layer must have the softmax activation function (guarantees the output to be between 0 and 1) and nb_classes neurons.
4. Train your model as usual
5. Use the predict function. You will receive a vector of size (nb_classes,1) containing the probabilities of each class.

Comment: Would you provide an example model?

Comment: You can find it here: https://keras.io , "Getting started: 30 seconds to Keras":

"
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
#Stacking layers is as easy as .add():
from keras.layers import Dense
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')) #i.e. nb_classes = 10
#Once your model looks good, configure its learning process with #.compile():
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])"